# How to create bean and autowire if the constructor has parameters?

Tags: spring-boot, parameters, autowired

I’m interested in Java configuration without .xml.
I have the following class:

```
public class MyClient extends org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
 {

    public MyClient(URI serverUri, Draft draft) {
        super(serverUri, draft);
    }

    public MyClient(URI serverURI) {
        super(serverURI);
    }

    public MyClient(URI serverUri, Map<String, String> httpHeaders) {
        super(serverUri, httpHeaders);
    }
```

…

Then I have other classes, extending MyClient:

```
MyClient1 extends MyClient;
MyClient2 extends MyClient;
```

For object creation from them, the first constructor is used:

```
public MyClient(URI serverUri, Draft draft) {
        super(serverUri, draft);
```

The question is – how to create appropriate beans and autowire them with a Spring Boot Controller? (say, the controller from this example):

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
  @MessageMapping("/hello")
  @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
  public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take bean from `ApplicationContext`
Example:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {

        MyClient myClient = (MyClient) applicationContext.getBean("myClient", param1, param2, ...);
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }

}
```